# not display from database

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

I'm trying to display list from database but when run that code it said "You have no product listed in your data yet" but actually have list from my data ...

```
<?php 
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "3250", "shopone");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// This block grabs the whole list of product for viewing
$product_list = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
             $product_id = $row["product_id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $product_category = $row["product_category"];
              $product_retail_price = $row["product_retail_price"];
              $product_price = $row["product_price"];
              $product_detail = $row["product_detail"];
              $product_image = $row["screenshot"];
              $product_thumbnail = $row["product_thumbnail"];
              $product_discount = $row["product_discount"];
            $screenshot = $row["screenshot"];

             $product_list .= '<table width="80%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="172" valign="top"> echo <img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot .'" width="111" height="149" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" /><br />
      <a href="../product_images/<?php echo $product_id; ?>.jpg">View Full Size Image</a></td>
    <td width="85" class="product-text">' . $product_id . '</td>
    <td width="402" class="product-text">' . $product_name . '</td>
    <td width="108" align="center" class="product-text">' . $product_price . '</td>
    <td width="34" align="center" class="product-text"><a rel="leanModal" href="edit_product.php?pid=' . $product_id . '">Edit</a></td>

    <td width="56" align="center" class="product-text"><a rel="leanModal" href="product.php?deleteid=' . $product_id . '">Delete</a></td>
        <td width="56" align="center" class="product-text"><a href="view_product.php?pid=' . $product_id . '">View</a></td>
  </tr>
</table> ';              

    }

    $product_list = "You have no product listed in your data yet";

?>
```

and then the result i get is showing nothing it said "you have no product list in your data" , how can i solve that!

Comment: You are building your table in your variable and then overwrite it with that message.

Comment: Also you dont need php tags inside that table.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last assignment to:

```
if (empty($product_list)) {
    $product_list = "You have no product listed in your data yet";
}
```

You were replacing all the results retrieved from the database with that error message.

All the places where you do `<?php echo ... ?>` in the `$product_list` assignments should be concatenation -- you can only use that in inline HTML, not in strings.

You probably don't want to start a new `<table>` for each row from the database. Usually there's just one HTML table, and each database row corresponds to one HTML row within it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the privilege problem. But first comment the last line and have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting $product_list in the last statement, that´s why you get the value you last gave to the variable.
Also, as a tip, in the while loop you can save the row for each record, as you already have it in the array.
Last, you can open the table before the while, and close it after.

```
<?php 
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "3250", "shopone");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// This block grabs the whole list of product for viewing
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//you can add this check to add 'empty table' message if no result
if(mysql_num_rows()>0)
{    
    $product_list = '<table>';         
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { 
       $product_list.= '<tr>'.
                       '<td>'.$row["product_id"].'</td>'.
                       // ....
                       // do the same with all rows
                       // ....
                       '<td>'.$row["screenshot"].'</td>'.
                       '</tr>';         
    }
    $product_list.= '</table>';
}
else
{
    $product_list = "You have no product listed in your data yet";
} 
//print
echo $product_list;
?>
```